# Return true if any value in an array contains error value

Tags: excel, vba

Just need to set a boolean to true if any value in an array (`array = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value`) contains #NA error.

I've read that `wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` can do this but I'm not sure how to apply it to my code. Any other methods would also be okay.

Comment: That method will return an error on itself if no `xlErrors` have been found.

Comment: probably best, to loop through `array` and check for errors.

Comment: If #N/A would be the only error value, you could just use: `ErrorFound = (application.sum(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion) = cverr(xlerrna))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub checkNAError()
   Dim wks As Worksheet, rngErr As Range, celV As Range
   
    Set wks = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need to check
    On Error Resume Next
      Set rngErr = wks.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngErr Is Nothing Then
        For Each celV In rngErr.cells
            If celV.value = CVErr(2042) Then MsgBox "#N\A error on cell " & celV.Address
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No any error in sheet " & wks.name
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jon: Do you need searching for "#NA error", as mentioned in your question, or only to identify an error? Anyhow, the above code should be efficient for both cases. For only an error, it can be made more compact...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code:

It's basically looking through all the values in the cells:

```vb
Sub check_for_errors()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim errorFound As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    arr = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value
    errorFound = False
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If IsError(arr(i, j)) Then
                errorFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If errorFound Then Exit For
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print errorFound
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does not specifically search for "#NA error" as required... And iterating between all cells of the sheet, instead of firstly making a range of cells containing errors may waste Excel resources. The OP specified, in a way, what to be used for handling the problem and it looks to be the most efficient, any how. But, since he marked it as accepted answer, everything OK...